# Mysql complex select query from 4 tables

Tags: mysql

I research almost 200 example pages about mysql complex queries but stuck in it.

This is my stucture

```
Table name: zones

zoneId | zoneName
------------------

Table name: customers

customesId | zoneId | customerName
----------------------------------

Table name: products

productId | productName
-----------------------

Table name: sales

sid | zoneId | customerId | productId | amount
----------------------------------------------
```

Is it possible to get the following output only with the query?

```
zoneName | customerName | productName   | amount(SUM)
---------------------------------------------------
ZoneX    | customerA    | productName_1 | 10
         |              | productName_2 | 0
         |              | productName_3 | 4
         |              | productName_4 | 0
ZoneX    | customerB    | productName_1 | 7
         |              | productName_2 | 0
         |              | productName_3 | 4
         |              | productName_4 | 3
.......
```

I want to get as "0" even customer or product has no sale

I tried:

```
SELECT zones.zoneName
     , customers.customerName
     , products.productName
     , SUM(amount) AS amount 
FROM customers 
INNER JOIN zones 
  ON customers.zoneId = zones.zoneId 
LEFT JOIN sales 
  ON customers.customerId = sales.customerId 
LEFT JOIN products 
  ON sales.productId = products.productId
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Though I don't know why you would want to not display zonex and customerA on every record.  additionally to get the 0 records you'd need to use an outer join.

Comment: Looks like you need to `sum(coalesce(Amount,0)) as Amount` and you'd need to cross join each customer to the products to handle when no sales are present.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application level code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cross join all the customers to the products so that each customer has every product listed regardless of sale.

```
SELECT z.zoneName
     , c.customerName
     , p.productName
     , SUM(coalesce(s.amount,0)) AS amount 
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN zones z 
  ON c.zoneId = z.zoneId 
CROSS JOIN PRODUCTS P
LEFT JOIN sales S
  ON c.customerId = s.customerId
 and s.productID = p.productID 
GROUP BY z.zoneName
       , c.customerName
       , p.productName
```

Comment: Note to OP: If you have `zones` without customers, you will need do a `CROSS JOIN` with zones first and `LEFT JOIN` with `customers`

Comment: Thanks Juan Carlos Oropeza. No. Each customer has zone. xQbert, can you update your answer as you told in your last comment. Sorry, its difficult to understant this kind comlepx query.

Comment: sorry but its returning 1 record after 150 seconds or more. I have 50 zones, 100 customers and 75000 sales. Becuse of that?

Comment: I mean. You may have Zones without Customers, and those Zones wont appear. If query is slow check index on your tables and execution plan. [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: no. All zones with customes and yes 1.26 second after change indexes thanks. But still 1 record? I dont know why. Any suggestion?

Comment: Missing `group by` simple yet silly omission by me.  the reason you only had one record is due to MySQL group by extensions that will select a value from the column if not in the group by when aggregation exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
SELECT c.zoneId ,c.customesId ,c.customerName,IF(s.amount IS NULL, 0 , s.amount) 
FROM customers AS c, products AS p
LEFT JOIN sales AS s ON s.productId  = p.productId  and s.customersid = c.customersid
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The comma operator has lower precedence than the explicit join operators, plus sales is related to a customer as well, not just to a product.